# Observe approximation order of numerical solution of a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

When solving a Partial Differential Equation numerically, I estimated the approximation orders theoretically as follows,
$$ u(x,t)= u_{h,k} + C_1 h^{p} +C_2 k^{q}, $$
where $ u_{h,k} $ is a numerical approximation to the solution function $ u(x,t) $, $ h $ is the size of the partitions on $ x\in [a,b] $, $ k $ is the size of the partitions on $ t\in [0,T] $, $ C_1 $ and $ C_2 $ are constants do not depend on $ h $ and $ k $.

Here, Do you know a way to observe these convergence orders $ p $ and $ q $ in a computational point of view?

That is, Is there a way to compute these orders using numerical data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the idea is correct, but I realized that the following way  answers my question.

Let us first try to find the order $p$, in order to do this, let us write approximate solutions for $h$, $h/2$, $h/4$,
$$u(x,t)= u_{h,k}+C_1 h^p +C_2 k^q, $$
$$u(x,t)= u_{h/2,k}+C_1 \left(\frac{h}{2}\right)^p +C_2 k^q, $$
$$u(x,t)= u_{h/4,k}+C_1 \left(\frac{h}{4}\right)^p +C_2 k^q. $$

Then, the following formula gives the order $p$,
$$ p = \frac{\ln |u_{h,k} - u_{h/2,k} |}{\ln | u_{h/2,k} - u_{h/4,k} |}/\ln 2. $$
Same way, we may write the following formula in order to find the order $q$,$$ q = \frac{\ln |u_{h,k} - u_{h,k/2} |}{\ln | u_{h,k/2} - u_{h,k/2} |}/\ln 2. $$